# AWS DynamoDB BOTO3 Confusing Scan

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Basically, if i loop a datetime performing an scan with date range per-day, like:

```
table_hook = dynamodb_resource.Table('table1')

date_filter = Key('date_column').between('2021-01-01T00:00:00+00:00', '2021-01-01T23:59:59+00:00')

response = table_hook.scan(FilterExpression=date_filter)
incoming_data = response['Items']

if (response['Count']) == 0:
    return

_counter = 1

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table_hook.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    if ( 
        parser.parse(response['Items'][0]['date_column']).replace(tzinfo=None) < parser.parse('2021-01-01T00:00:00+00:00').replace(tzinfo=None) 
            or 
        parser.parse(response['Items'][0]['date_column']).replace(tzinfo=None).replace(tzinfo=None) > parser.parse('2021-06-07T23:59:59+00:00').replace(tzinfo=None) 
    ):
        break
        
    incoming_data.extend(response['Items'])
    _counter+=1
    print("|->   Getting page %s" % _counter)
```

At the end of Day1 to Day2 loop, it retrieve me X rows,

But if i perform the same scan at the same way (paginating), with the same range (Day1 to Day2), without doing a loop, it retrieve me Y rows,

And to become better, when i perform a table.describe_table(TableName='table1'), row_count field comes with Z rows, i literally dont understand what is going on!

Comment: are these large documents? (Not rows, documents - the correct terminology helps keep the fact that Dynamo NoSQL is **not** an sql database)

Scan returns x documents up to a certain size limit. If your documents in the table are very large, then fewer will be returned per pagination. 

Also describe_table row_count is an estimation, as Count is not really a supported function of DynamoDb due to the way its structured.

You seem to be trying to treat Dynamo like an SQL table here - what you are trying to do here would be much better suited if your `date` attr was the Sort Key.

Comment: then you could simply do a query against the particular Partion Key of the type fo record you want to retrieve, `key(pk).eq(some_value) && Key(sortKey).gte(earlieest date) && Key(sortKey).lte(latest_date)`

Comment: So yes, at all, contains ~900 mb of documents,  thanks for the NoSQL hint, i perform the scan with your filter expression .gte() and .lte() and it returned less results in the same range within my old filter expression, actually i convert it to pandas.DataFrame, using pd.DataFrame(incoming_data), maybe this a reason?

Comment: I found the problem @lynkfox it was my paginating, do you know some whay to deal with it? i already learned the official API, but, atm, nothing resolves

Comment: there isnt really. The limit on how big the response coming back from a given page is set by AWS.

Dynamo isnt really meant for large file storage - you could store them in an s3 and keep the key to said object in the dynamo, which would drastically lower the size of your documents - and allow you to hit the document limit per page rater than the size limit, which would remain more constant

Comment: Actually, using my FilterExpression or yours, i pass 2021-03-15 up to 2021-03-15T23:59:59 and in the first response i got documents from the past year, idk why these filters are not working

Comment: filters filter the response *after* its been called. So when you make a call with a scan or query then you get back the first page. THEN filter is applied to that to filter back what is there.

Since it sounds like you aren't using a sort key - as such, they aren't coming back in necessarily the same order in the pages either, which is another potential reason you get back different numbers each page.

Comment: Testing `response['Count'] == 0` is not the correct way to determine that there are no matching items. It's quite possible that *every* item returned by the scan was filtered out of the results by your filterexpression, resulting in a Count of zero, yet there may still be more matching items. Test for absence of `LastEvaluatedKey` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on help of above guys, i found my error, basically i'm not passing the filter again when performing pagination so the fixed code are:

```
table_hook = dynamodb_resource.Table('table1')

date_filter = Key('date_column').between('2021-01-01T00:00:00+00:00', '2021-01-01T23:59:59+00:00')

response = table_hook.scan(FilterExpression=date_filter)
incoming_data = response['Items']

_counter = 1

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table_hook.scan(FilterExpression=date_filter,
                ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
        
    incoming_data.extend(response['Items'])
    _counter+=1
    print("|->   Getting page %s" % _counter)
```